# I want to insert numbers in my list view at position 0 or first column (Asp.net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is my code:

I want to pass a value to 0th position of list view.
I have tried this technique, but it was not working:

```cs
int i;   
int item1 = Convert.ToInt32(listView_pro.Items.Count);//convert total no.of row in listview
ListViewItem row1 = new ListViewItem();
for (i = 0; i <= listView_pro.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    foreach(ListViewItem items in this.listView_pro.Items )
    {
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem item2 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
        item2 = Convert.ToInt32(++i);
        listView_pro.Items[0].SubItems[0] = item2;
    }
}
```

Comment: No SQL involved?

Comment: no .there is no sql

Comment: `if(i==0){ items = item2;}` You can assign in first iteration of for loop and foreach element

Comment: can u please explain .!